# split jdbc query with long range into smaller chunks by time

Tags: java, jdbc, time, chunks

I'm working on a java application where I want to be able to dynamically import data from another database, and be able to expand the imported time range later. I'd like to have clear chunks in time (for example a month, expanded to a year or two later).

The problem is, that there is also a lot of rows in the database, so even while importing a month I'd like to split it into smaller pieces (say a day at a time).

Every example I'm finding splits the data by row count, so is there no elegant way to do it? The best I'm coming up with is to take the start day, add one days worth of milliseconds to it and from there generate the query for one days data on the fly (and so on until it goes over the end day). However that feels hackish...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use LIMIT after each query, like:
Select * from oldbd where time < foo and time < bar LIMIT 0 , 1000
and the next one 1001 , 2000 etc.
As long as no new rows for this time-range are added, this works very well, not only seperating it into chunks but also every of these chunks is like-sized in bytes, as there is the exact same size of rows for every query.

Comment: Thanks, though it's not exactly what I'm looking for. To be honest looking further I'm not really even sure if what I was trying to do is sensible at all... Anyway, I just decided to iterate a day at a time by creating calendars and getting the resultset for one day and then running currentTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); to generate the date ranges for the next days query.